# Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.UserAppDataPath + @"\MyFolder") not working when called in Clickonce Application

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

I am working on a dot net application, in which I want a folder structure created under user's roaming directory.

When I debug the code folder structure is created just fine. for example following code works:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.UserAppDataPath + @"\MyFolder")
```

But after the ClickOnce Deployment, and on execution of same application through ClickOnce, the same folder structure could not get created.

Not sure, but looks like some ClickOnce limitation. OR it is an access issue in Windows 7? 
Just wondering, is it like ClickOnce is not be able to read/write in roaming profile folder structure?

Can someone please help me understand?

Hi, thanks for your answers so far, I just came across the following link
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2571899

Microsoft ClickOnce deployment is not supported with Roaming Profiles.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: There was no errors, just nothing happens.

Comment: As I said same code works fine in debug mode. There is no error or exception.

Comment: Let's see some code then.

Comment: is it working in the same system in which the application was developed?

Comment: You should use [Path.Combine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of concatenating strings.

Answer (score 0):

Put your CreateDirectory function with in a try block, and display or log exception caught to root cause the issue.

Possible exceptions as mentioned in following msdn article help you to debug the issue

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answers so far, I just came across the following link

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2571899

Microsoft ClickOnce deployment is not supported with Roaming Profiles.